# Meteor query sort error "Requests.find(...).sort is not a function"

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I need to sort "datetime" ascending format. But getting an error "`Requests.find(...).sort is not a function`" meteor mini mongo find

```
var results = Requests.find({
    "sp_id": request.sp_id,
    "slot": request.slot,
    "date": request.date,
    "datetime": {
        '$gte': request.datetime
    },
    "status": {
        $nin: ['cancel', 'completed']
    }
}
).sort({datetime: 1}).fetch();

console.log(results);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
const query = { your: 'query' };
const options = { sort: { datetime: 1 } };

const results = Requests.find(query, options).fetch();
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html).